# Wicket9: How to compress (minimize) HTML before sending to user?

Tags: java, wicket

I know how to compress JavaScript and CSS resources before sending to client

using

```
getResourceSettings().setCssCompressor(new MyCssCompressor());
getResourceSettings().setJavaScriptCompressor(
        new MyJavaScriptCompressor);
```

is there anything similar for HTML markup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an HTML Compressor library in [WicketStuff-Core](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/htmlcompressor-parent)

The usage looks like:

```
public class HtmlCompressorApp extends AbstractApp {
   @Override
    protected void init()      {
      super.init();
      if (usesDeploymentConfig()) {
        getMarkupSettings().setMarkupFactory(new HtmlCompressingMarkupFactory());
        // if we want custom settings for our compressor we could do this instead:
        // HtmlCompressor compressor = new HtmlCompressor();
        // compressor.setPreserveLineBreaks(true);
        // getMarkupSettings().setMarkupFactory(new HtmlCompressingMarkupFactory(compressor));
      }
    }
}
```

Maven coordinates: org.wicketstuff:wicketstuff-htmlcompressor:9.4.0